# Iterating table cells using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table where I need to get the values of all the rows of a table, within each table there exist cells with different classes.

- The first one contains a checkbox, when selected it must return true else false
- The second is a inner text itself
- The third column needs a number to be fetched from input type=number
- The fourth is a text from textbox
- The last 2 are the dates which should be the inner text itself.

The expected result is

```
[
[false,"A text",12,"textboxvalueifpresent","2019-07-17T14:08:38.911Z","2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z"],
[true,"B text",88,"","2019-07-17T14:08:38.913Z","2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z"],
[false,"C text",24,"","2019-07-17T14:08:38.913Z","2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z"]
]
```

I have tried with for each of Jquery

```js
var items = [];
$("#tab1 tr").each(function() {
        items.push([$(this).find("input.checkbox").val(),
        $(this).find("input.material").val(),
        $(this).find("input.consign").val(),
        $(this).find("input.name").val(),
        $(this).find("input.dc").val(),
        $(this).find("input.do").val(),
        ]);
});
```

```html
<table id="tab1" style="padding: 5px;width: 100%">
   <tr id="tr1">
      <td class="input checkbox" style="width:5%;cursor:default"><input type="checkbox" id="cb1"></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><span style="width:100%;" class="input material" id="ma1">A text</span></td>
      <td style="width:10%;"><input type="number" style="width:90%;" class="input consign" id="co1" value="12" placeholder="Consign"></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><input style="width:90%;" class="input name" id="na1" value="" placeholder="Name"></td>
      <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input dr" id="dr1">2019-07-17T14:08:38.911Z</span></td>
      <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input do" id="do1">2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="tr2">
      <td class="input checkbox" style="width:5%;cursor:default"><input type="checkbox" id="cb2"></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><span style="width:100%;" class="input material" id="ma2">B text</span></td>
      <td style="width:10%;"><input type="number" style="width:90%;" class="input consign" id="co2" value="88" placeholder="Consign"></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><input style="width:90%;" class="input name" id="na2" value="" placeholder="Name"></td>
      <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input dr" id="dr2">2019-07-17T14:08:38.913Z</span></td>
      <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input do" id="do2">2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z</span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="tr3">
      <td class="input checkbox" style="width:5%;cursor:default"><input type="checkbox" id="cb3"></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><span style="width:100%;" class="input material" id="ma3">C text</span></td>
      <td style="width:10%;"><input type="number" style="width:90%;" class="input consign" id="co3" value="24" placeholder="Consign"></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><input style="width:90%;" class="input name" id="na3" value="" placeholder="Name"></td>
      <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input dr" id="dr3">2019-07-17T14:08:38.913Z</span></td>
      <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input do" id="do3">2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `input.material` should be `span.material`, and `.val()` should be `.text()`.

Comment: The same for all the other cells that contain spans rather than inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of a checkbox is whatever is in it's `value` attribute, it doesn't matter whether it's checked. You can use `.prop("checked")` or `.is(":checked")` to tell whether it's checked.

Your checkboxes don't have `class="checkbox", so`.input.checkbox`won't work. I changed it to`.input:checkbox`.

Spans will not be selected with `input` selectors, and you get the text with `.text()`, not `.val()`.

You don't have `class="dc"` in the fifth column, it's `class="dr"`.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var items = [];
  $("#tab1 tr").each(function() {
    items.push([
      $(this).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked"),
      $(this).find("span.material").text(),
      $(this).find("input.consign").val(),
      $(this).find("input.name").val(),
      $(this).find("span.dr").text(),
      $(this).find("span.do").text(),
    ]);
  });
  $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(items, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab1" style="padding: 5px;width: 100%">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td class="input checkbox" style="width:5%;cursor:default"><input type="checkbox" id="cb1"></td>
    <td style="width:30%;"><span style="width:100%;" class="input material" id="ma1">A text</span></td>
    <td style="width:10%;"><input type="number" style="width:90%;" class="input consign" id="co1" value="12" placeholder="Consign"></td>
    <td style="width:30%;"><input style="width:90%;" class="input name" id="na1" value="" placeholder="Name"></td>
    <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input dr" id="dr1">2019-07-17T14:08:38.911Z</span></td>
    <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input do" id="do1">2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
    <td class="input checkbox" style="width:5%;cursor:default"><input type="checkbox" id="cb2"></td>
    <td style="width:30%;"><span style="width:100%;" class="input material" id="ma2">B text</span></td>
    <td style="width:10%;"><input type="number" style="width:90%;" class="input consign" id="co2" value="88" placeholder="Consign"></td>
    <td style="width:30%;"><input style="width:90%;" class="input name" id="na2" value="" placeholder="Name"></td>
    <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input dr" id="dr2">2019-07-17T14:08:38.913Z</span></td>
    <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input do" id="do2">2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3">
    <td class="input checkbox" style="width:5%;cursor:default"><input type="checkbox" id="cb3"></td>
    <td style="width:30%;"><span style="width:100%;" class="input material" id="ma3">C text</span></td>
    <td style="width:10%;"><input type="number" style="width:90%;" class="input consign" id="co3" value="24" placeholder="Consign"></td>
    <td style="width:30%;"><input style="width:90%;" class="input name" id="na3" value="" placeholder="Name"></td>
    <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input dr" id="dr3">2019-07-17T14:08:38.913Z</span></td>
    <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input do" id="do3">2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="button">Show array</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the **checked property** of the checkbox and that is check by the **is()** method. And span did not have val method to get value. It is Html tag so you should do **.text() or .html()** to get the tag text or html. Also if you have classes on every control then you should find directly by class name.

I added the checkbox class to the checkbox control and get the checked property.

```
var items = [];
$("#tab1 tr").each(function() {
        items.push([$(this).find(".checkbox").is(":checked"),
        $(this).find(".material").text(),
        $(this).find(".consign").val(),
        $(this).find(".name").val(),
        $(this).find(".dc").text(),
        $(this).find(".do").text(),
        ]);
});

<table id="tab1" style="padding: 5px;width: 100%">
   <tr id="tr1">
      <td class="input checkbox" style="width:5%;cursor:default"><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" class="checkbox"></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><span style="width:100%;" class="input material" id="ma1">A text</span></td>
      <td style="width:10%;"><input type="number" style="width:90%;" class="input consign" id="co1" value="12" placeholder="Consign"></td>
      <td style="width:30%;"><input style="width:90%;" class="input name" id="na1" value="" placeholder="Name"></td>
      <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input dr" id="dr1">2019-07-17T14:08:38.911Z</span></td>
      <td style="width:15%;"><span class="input do" id="do1">2019-07-04T12:00:00.000Z</span></td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

I think this should work.

Comment: You can also use $(this).find(".material").html() for the span tag. It is up to you what you need.

Comment: A good answer should explain what was wrong and how you fixed it, not just post new code.